# Is there a more efficient alternative to jQuery's $.load() method?

Tags: jquery

My question regards the use of jQuery's `.load()` method. The code below loads some content from a page on my site, into the current one.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    $('#result').load("mywebpage.html #report");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

This works well, but as I understand it, the `.load()` method as used above, actually returns *mywebpage.html* in it's entirety, just to get the contents of div named `#report`.

If mywebpage.html was an especially large file, and I had a busy site, then I'd want to optimise this call, so that it just returned the contents of the `#report` div.

Is jQuery capable of doing this on a static html-only website?

Comment: How can you only download partial contents of a filewithout knowing the file structure, which requires downloading the file? What does jQuery have to do with this? The problem here is the *server*, not the client. You are requesting the wrong thing, perhaps because it's not your site.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Relax dude, no need to get militant. And yes you are right, you did understand the question better, I actually deleted my comment a second before your aggressive response.

Comment: @Stephan You suggested I claimed the question was invalid. I never did any such thing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I never really said you claimed the question was invalid, I just said "It is a valid question".  (OK, so maybe I implied it.)

Comment: @Stephan I clearly typed in the word **suggested** for a good reason.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Are you sure that word 'suggested' was typed into the original comment?  You seem to be editing your comments after it was responded to.

Comment: @Stephan. I am absolutely, 100% positive what I said. I'm not the one misunderstanding people left and right here ;)

Comment: ...and you seem to be deleting yours, then jumping down my throat for not getting the memo quickly enough. Fair enough?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: By the way, what happened to your 'militant' comment...? :)

Comment: ha ha, these comments cracked me up. AndrewBarber and Stefan, thanks for your advice, I see now that jQuery (and JS in general) can, as @Manisearth points out below, only request whole files, and that the concept of partials doesn't yet exist. Hopefully it will, sometime in the future.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch The concept of "partials" is alive and well: create a url the returns only the *partial* information you need.

Comment: @Stephan You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means. It absolutely does not apply even remotely to anything I have posted here today. I sometimes get "militant" about SQL Injection, but none of that here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Unfortunately though, you deleted the comment in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is jQuery capable of doing this on a static html-only website?

## NO

jQuery is, after all, javascript. The `.load()` method will be AJAX-based. And AJAX can only fetch full files. Even if it could fetch partial files, it would still need to fetch the full file to _find out where the div is in the first place.

If you had access to the server, you *could* make a PHP page using an XML parser that does this. If you only ever want to load that element, keep it in a separate html file. Otherwise, nope.

Comment: reminds me almost immediately of http://stickerish.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/NoGuyBlackSS.png

Comment: it boggles my mind why you would need jQuery to load static content in the first place ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful info. @AndrewBarber I'm actually using it to load dynamic content in a rails app, but wanted to figure out how it all works by doing it on an html-only app first, and it's definitely helped my understanding.

Comment: Kinda like learning how to drive a car by using a toy wagon to roll a ton of wood down the hill when you already know how to drive a truck, but OK!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just create a `myreport.html` which only contains stuff you need from that big HTML and load it as per required

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    $('#result').load("myreport.html");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```